# Access a video file from a separate drive - ERROR: Not allowed to load local resource

Tags: apache, google-chrome, firefox, html5-video, wampserver

Wamp site is hosted local on C.

When I try and load a video file from my F drive - I get an access error.  If I load the HTML file without using WAMP it plays the video fine.

I've read it has to do with either .htaccess or httpd.conf - but everything I've found doesn't pertain to my actual use case.

EDIT - this appears to be a problem with Firefox and Chrome - just worked on IE

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with .htaccess or httpd.conf or any other configuration. It is simply a security constrained imposed by the browser.

Suppose that you have a webpage that loads some files from the local filesystem and then sends their contents to a server. Every user that visits your website will have their files read and sent to the server without this user event realizing. This is an obvious security problem and that's why  websites (loaded over http or https) can load resources only over https(s) and not from the local filesystem. Static html pages loaded directly from the filesystem (without an http server) don't pose this risk and can load file resources from the local filesystem.